# Image is not saved to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I´m working on a test project, in order to learn and understand C# and WPF. I have a button that opens an explorer window. I want to save the selected file (an image) to the database (SQL 2012) in a column of type varbinary(max).

And I´m failing, the updated "selectedCellphone" with the image is not saved to the DB. While debugging, I noticed that the object "saveCellphones" is correct, the attribute "Photo" is the byte[] from the image. And the method throws no exception whatsoever.

```
private void importPhotoButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Bilddateien (*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|Alle Dateien (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    ofd.ShowDialog();

    byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);


    try
    {
        using (var context = new CellphoneManagerEntities())
        {
            if (selectedCellphone != null)
            {
                selectedCellphone.Photo = data;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you connect your "selectedCellphone" to the context? There should be something like "context.Cellphones.Add(selectedCellphone)". Do you get any data in the database at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `selectedCellPhone`? It is not defined in the code you are posting.

I *suspect* you use `selectedCellphone` elsewhere in your code, and it is an entity that yuo have retrieved from your database using a context.

**However**, when you call `SaveChanges()` on a context, this is most certainly a different context from the one you used to retrieve your `selectedCellphone`!

There *are no changes to save in the context that you are saving*!

In order for any changes to be saved, you need to make the changes in the context that you are saving.

One way to do this, if you do not have the original context available, would be something like this:

```
using (var context = new CellphoneManagerEntities())
{
    var updateCellphone = context.CellPhones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == selectedCellphone.Id);
    if (updateCellphone != null)
    {
        updateCellphone.Photo = data;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

By the way, you are retrieving your `byte[]` even if nothing may be saved. Unless you use it elsewhere, why not move it inside you `if`:

```
updateCellphone.Photo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I retrieved selectedCellphone in a different context. It worked right away when I retrieved it again in this new context, as you pointed out. Thank you.

Comment: @JannisAlexakis: whenever I see (also in my own code) something like "I'm using Linq and hey, updates are not working", the _first_ thought is by now "let's check and double check the context". **Context is everything** :)

Comment: It´s a bad habit from my Java projects: I always declare the EntityManager as class variable, in order to have the same persistence context in the entire class.